# Representation of integers by Fibonacci numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers, additive-combinatorics

Denote by $F$ the set of all Fibonacci numbers.
It is our conjecture that:

**(a)** For every integer $n$ there exist a number $k=2^q$ (for some positive integer $q$) and  numbers $a_1,\cdots,a_k\in F$ such that 
$$
n=a_1+\cdots+a_{\frac{k}{2}}-(a_{\frac{k}{2}+1}+\cdots+a_k).
$$
Now, denote by $k(n)$ the least $k$ obtained from (a).

**(b)** The set of all $k(n)$, where $n$ runs over all integers, is unbounded above.

(the **second part** is very important for me)

Comment: Do you consider $0$ a Fibonacci number?

Comment: Do the $a_j$ have to be pairwise distinct, or can there be repeats among them?

Comment: Thinking about it some more I assume $0$ does not count, or that would make $a$ not too hard.

Comment: @Nitin. No, ($F_1=F_2=1$ and $ F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$ ).

Comment: @Mitchell Spector, They can be repeated.

Comment: $F_0=0$ ***is*** a Fibonacci number, so you need to exclude it explicitly.

Comment: Fibonacci sequence is a [complete sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_sequence). Maybe, can be useful for your question.

Comment: I think for b) it should suffice to consider $$ \sum_{i=1}^n F_{3i}$$ or the like.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a proof of (a).  First we'll prove a little fact:

*Claim:* Every positive Fibonacci number can be written in the form $a_1+\cdots+a_{\frac{k}{2}}-(a_{\frac{k}{2}+1}+\cdots+a_k)$ for *every* $k\ge 2$ that is a power of $2.$

You can prove this by induction on $k,$ as follows:

$\bullet\;$ For $k=2,$ $F_n=F_{n+2}-F_{n+1}.$

$\bullet\;$ If $F_n=a_1+\cdots+a_{\frac{k}{2}}-(a_{\frac{k}{2}+1}+\cdots+a_k),$ then write each of the $a_j$ as a difference of two Fibonacci numbers (each $a_j,$ being a Fibonacci number itself, is the difference of the next two Fibonacci numbers).  That expresses $F_n$ as a formula of the same form but with twice as many terms, as desired, proving the claim.

Here's a more detailed description of the induction step above.  We're assuming that $F_n=a_1+\cdots+a_{\frac{k}{2}}-(a_{\frac{k}{2}+1}+\cdots+a_k),$ where each $a_k$ is some Fibonacci number; say $a_k$ is the $s_k^{\,\text{th}}$ Fibonacci number, so that $a_k=F_{s_k}.$ Then
\begin{align}
F_n&=\sum_{j=1}^{k/2}a_j -\sum_{j=k/2 + 1}^{k}a_j
\\&=\sum_{j=1}^{k/2}F_{s_j} -\sum_{j=k/2 + 1}^{k}F_{s_j}
\\&=\sum_{j=1}^{k/2}(F_{s_j+2}-F_{s_j+1}) -\sum_{j=k/2 + 1}^{k}(F_{s_j+2}-F_{s_j+1})
\\&=\sum_{j=1}^{k/2}F_{s_j+2}+\sum_{j=k/2 + 1}^{k}F_{s_j+1}-\big(\sum_{j=1}^{k/2}F_{s_j+1}+\sum_{j=k/2 + 1}^{k}F_{s_j+2}\big),
\end{align}
which is the sum of $k$ Fibonacci numbers minus the sum of $k$ Fibonacci numbers, as desired.
$$ $$
Now, let $x$ be any positive number; we'll show by induction that we can write $x$ in the required form. If $x$ is a Fibonacci number, we're done. If not, let $F_n$ be the greatest positive Fibonacci number less than $x$ (we know that $x\gt 1,$ so $F_n$ exists).  By induction, we can write $x-F_n$ in the required form for some $k.$ By the claim, we can write $F_n$ in the required form for the same $k,$ and this lets us write $x$ in the desired form for $2k.$

Comment: In the induction step, what if one of your $a_j$ are one?

Comment: @Nitin $ 1=2-1.$

Comment: $-1$ isn't a Fibonacci number though?

Comment: For example what are you doing about (2+1) - (1+1)?

Comment: @Nitin $2$ would be included with the Fibonacci numbers being added, and $1$ would be included with the Fibonacci numbers being subtracted.

Comment: Look at the example of 2+1 - (1+1). That would turn into (1+1) + (2-1) - (2-1) - (2-1) or 1+1+2 +1+1-(1+2+2) under your algorithm

Comment: So there are 5 terms added and 3 terms subtracted.

Comment: @Nitin For your specific example where you trying to produce a value of $1,$ compute $1=3-2,$ and now use $3=8-5$ and $2=5-3$ to yield $(8+3)-(5+5).$  I don't think you can get $(2+1)-(1+1)$ from the method I suggested, but if you could, it's no problem -- that still fits the OP's requirements.

Comment: No. In the general case, you have $k$ values being added and $k$ being subtracted. If there are $m$ ones in the $k$ being added but none being subtracted, each of the $k-m$ non $1$ terms will split into two, but each of the $m$ 1s will only give you $m$ positive terms. It doesn't work in general unless you can show that there will always be an equal number of $1$s bein added and subtracted.

Comment: If you have $m$ $1\text{s}$ being added, then, at the next stage, they're replaced by $m$ $2\text{s}$ being added  and $m$ $1\text{s}$ being subtracted (or, alternatively, by $m$ $3\text{s}$ being added  and $m$ $2\text{s}$ being subtracted).  I'll add to my answer a detailed description of how it works.

Comment: I'm sorry, I understand now. Apologies for the density.

Comment: @Nitin -- No problem, it probably needed a better description to be clear. I've added some details to the answer.

Comment: You're very gracious. Do you have any idea about (b)?

Comment: @Nitin If I had an answer for (b), I'd post it!

Answer (score 1):

For the first claim - it suffices to show this for natural numbers, since for the negative integers you can replace the labels $a_i \mapsto a_{k-i}$. It's clear that $0 = a_1 - a_2$, where $a_1 = a_2$ are any Fibonacci number.

Suppose this holds up to $m$. Then we can write

$$ m=a_1+\cdots+a_{\frac{k}{2}}-(a_{\frac{k}{2}+1}+\cdots+a_k). $$
$$ 1=2+1\cdots+1-(1+\dots + 1). $$

so that $m+1$ is the sum of $k$ positive terms follows by $k$ negative terms.

For the second claim - I don't have a full answer yet. It's trivial to write any Fibonacci number $F_n > 3$ in such a form with $k = 2$, so by the above construction any number $x$ should be expressible with $k = 2^{F_{n-1}}$ terms, where $F_n$ is the greatest Fibonacci number less than $x$.

And in fact, for any number of the form $x = F_n + b$ where $1 \leq b \leq 8$ we have $k(x) \leq 4$, since each of the number $1$ through $8$ can be written as the difference of two Fibonacci terms.

The first natural number we can't express as a difference of two Fibonacci terms is $9$. I'm still trying to show that $k(F_n + 9) > 4$ for $n > 8$.